# how can I show the sub menu container on hover

Tags: html, css, nav, submenu, megamenu

How can I get it so when I hover over Menu item 2 it will show the submenu-container?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/paulmaximus/pen/NWRrrdY)

Do I need to add something on the LI or the A tag? I have tried

```
ul li a:hover .submenu-container {
    display: block;
}
```

but it didn't work

```
 <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    </li>        

 </ul>
 <div class="submenu-container">
    <ul class="Sub-Menu">
           <h3>SubMenu 1</h3>
       <li>
           <a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a>
       </li>
       <li>
           <a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a>
       </li>        
    </ul>



* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.submenu-container {
    padding: 50px 20px;
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

Your ideas are appreciated.

Many thanks

Paul

Comment: `a:hover .submenu-container` this selects a element with the class `.submenu-container` that is inside the `a` element so you need to place the dropdown in the `a` tag to modify it like this on hover

Comment: So how do i get my submenu container to show?

Comment: First of all your css for submenu-container contains two display properties.

Comment: its solved, but thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would organize so that the submenu div is inside the menu 2 `li` and add:

```
ul li:hover .submenu-container {
  display: block;
}
```

See the full working example here:

```css
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .submenu-container {
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 50px 20px;
        background-color: red;
        display: none;
    }
ul li:hover .submenu-container {
  display: block;
}
    
    ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    ul li {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
    
    ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
```

```html
<div class=wrap>    

<ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
          <div class="submenu-container">
        <ul class="Sub-Menu">
            <h3>SubMenu 1</h3>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a>
        </li>        
    </ul>
  </div>
        </li>        
    </ul>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've changed you css selector to `ul li:hover .submenu-container`
And then moved your sub-menu so it is inside the li with the hover selector

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.submenu-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 50px 20px;
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

ul li:hover .submenu-container {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <div class="submenu-container">
      <ul class="Sub-Menu">
        <h3>SubMenu 1</h3>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: This only sort of works,  your sub menu disappears when trying to hover over it. See my answer for the proper way to do it.

Comment: thank you, yours would have worked if you didn't use the + symbol. With the + symbol I  can't go into my sub menu e.g it disappears when I move off menu 2

Comment: Yeah you where right I've edited the answer